I'm Gettting an error "npm ERR! enoent spawn node --max-old-space-size=10240 ENOENT" when I install node modules
I've an react + dotnet application. Also I have node installed on my machine. But when I used command
"npm  install" after cloning the repository. I get the error.
Screenshot of the error (https://i.sstatic.net/1EuX2.png)
I want to properly intall node modules
